# fill textbox with mysql data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

How do I fill an inputbox with mysql data. So that I can update the database?
I have this code that will show the table corresponding to the users request. But I don't know the syntax on how I can fill an inputbox with mysql data.

```
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE STAT='{$_POST["stat1"]}'");


    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
 <th>HospNum</th>
     <th>RoomNum</th>
 <th>LastName</th>
   <th>FirstName</th>
   <th>MidName</th>
    <th>Address</th>
   <th>TelNum</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Nurse</th>
   </tr>";

   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
   echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['HOSPNUM'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['ROOMNUM'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['LASTNAME'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['FIRSTNAME'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['MIDNAME'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['ADDRESS'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['TELNUM'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['STAT'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['NURSE'] . "</td>";
```

echo "";
  }
       echo "";

And I want to display the corresponding records with this html form, by inputting a primary key. And clicking the search button, the record will appear on each box. Just like when you update mysql database through phpmyadmin. But this time using a custom html form.

```
<td width="168"><input name="hnum" type="text" id="hospnum"></td>
<td width="41"><font size="3">Room #</td>
<td width="3">:</td>
 <td width="168"><input name="rnum" type="text" id="rnum"></td>
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input name="hnum" type="text" id="hospnum" value="<?php echo $row['ROOMNUM']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In text field you have fill the value attribute with php fetched attribute value

```
echo "<input name='rnum' type='text' id='rnum' value =".$row['ROOMNUM'].">";
```